# Can any continuous complex function be written as the sum of a holomorphic and antiholomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a continuous function $h\in C^0$, can it always be decomposed into a sum of a holomorphic function $f\in C^{\omega}$ and an antiholomorphic function $g$ (where $\bar g\in C^{\omega}$)?

Comment: Hint: Holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions are real-analytic.

Comment: And harmonic (stronger than real-analytic)

Comment: In a simply connected domain $h=f+\bar g$ iff $h$ harmonic - enough to show for $h$ real harmonic as we can add the results for $h_1+ih_2$ - and then there is $F=h+iv$ holomorphic and $h=(F+\bar F)/2$ - if the domain is not simply connected one has a local representation as above but may not be global